# get value from database based on array in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, arrays, codeigniter, select

I have an array

```
$user = array([0]=>1 [1]=>2 [2]=>3)
```

which contains id's of certain users.
I need to get the countries of these users from database.

```
foreach($userid as $user){
    $this->db->select('country');
    $this->db->where('user_id',$user);
    $this->db->from('company');
    $usercountry = $this->db->get();
    $count = $usercountry->row();
    $country = $count->country;
    }
```

Suppose user1 has country ES, user2 has IN, user3 has US, user4 has UK. then if array contains 1,2,3. Then i need to get the countries ES,IN,US.

Comment: can you upvote if my answer is useful for you..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way normal query for this kind of array's

```
public function get_countries($user)
{
 $query = "select country from company where user_id IN($user)";
 $result = $this->db->query($query);
 if($res->num_rows()>0){
        return $res->result("array");
    }
    return array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. No need for loop with multiple queries - instead use `WHERE id IN (1,2,3);` or the CodeIgniter equivalent - `$this->db->where_in();`
2. If you have ID's representing different countries you can create a table in the DB that has a list of the countries coupled with their id's. Then when you fetch data from your `users` table you can always    [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) the country from that table by using the common chain in the link - the `country_id` (This is known as FOREIGN KEY and it creates relationship between tables).